# Can PHP handle a PDF form submitted as a complete PDF document

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload

**In Short:**

I have a PDF that customers can fill out.  When they press the "Submit" button, I want to automatically send an email with the completed PDF attached.  This should happen server-side with no further interaction from the customer.

**In Long:**

Currently I have the PDF set to post the data to the server as html form data.  My PHP script then processes this data and sends a plain text email with the data.  The people receiving the email would prefer to have a copy of the actual PDF, not just plain text.

So, in Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro, I set the Submit button to submit as "PDF The complete document" (as seen below).

[image]

The problem is, I don't know what to do in PHP to handle this.  I assumed it would upload to the server as part of the `$_FILES` array, but `print_r($_FILES)` shows an empty array, and the `count` of both `$_FILES` and `$_POST` is `0`.

So my question is, what's happening to the uploaded pdf?  and is there anything I can do with PHP to turn that pdf into an email attachment?  I don't think I'm running into issues with the file size; the `post_max_size` is 2MB, and the PDF is only about ~725kb.

---

I actually ended up sending the FDF data to the server instead of the whole PDF. This meant I had to write a whole bunch of gibberish into my PHP to handle the FDF, but all-in-all it's a smaller upload and it meets the customer's requirements. If you really need to upload the whole PDF, [Patrick's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267909/388639) should be correct -- you should be able to find the uploaded pdf in `$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']`.

Comment: Check the server's access log. If the whole PDF was being sent, you'd see a hit on the server of 725+kb in size, and have your PHP script dump out as much information as it can from the request headers. A wiresniffer may of use on the client machine to see exactly what Acrobat is sending out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the raw PDF data from **$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'].**  You can output this to a file and open it as you would any PDF.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I stumbled upon an answer similar to this (after I had chosen to go a different route). I lost the link before I remembered to answer my own question, but I think you essentially said the same thing.  Thanks!