# How can I echo the XML that is sent from a PDF form in a PHP Page?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, httprequest

I have a PDF form that sends it information as XML.  I want to echo out the xml data in a PHP file to test the format, etc.  Here is what I have tried and it does not work

```
$xml    = file_get_contents('php://input');
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->XML($xml);

while ($reader->read()) {
    foreach ($reader as $name => $value) {
        echo "$name: $value\n";
    }
}
// this line will echo out the values of the xml one after the
// other without spaces. I am looking for name: value.
echo "<br>$xml<br>";
```

Comment: does not work... how? did you confirm that `$xml` actually contains xml text? Did you confirm that XMLReader accepts that (supposed) xml? did you confirm that the pdf is actually sending anything to begin with? these are not things we can guess at. YOU have to do some basic debugging first.

Comment: wow, I have a PDF with the submit action set to XML... so I figured that Adobe would package up the payload as XML.  So no I did not check that.  I did check that the fields I filled in do come across in the payload, except they are just strung right together.  So that is the basic debugging I have done first.

Comment: "strung right together"? Are you viewing that in a browseR? rmember that the browser will see the xml tags as (probably) unknown html tags and just render their contents. try a view-source and look at the raw data.

Comment: Adobe is sending  with the options you can set in a submit form button on LifeCyle Designer    XML Data Package (XDP)
Allows you to send the document and its components as an XML package
PDF
Submits the PDF template along with any filled-in data. Note: Submitting PDF will work if you have Adobe Acrobat® software installed, or if your PDF file has had its functionality extended using Adobe LiveCycle Reader Extensions software
XML Data (XML)
Submits only the XML form data
URL-encoded Data (HTTP post)
Submits your form data in a format used by HTML forms

Comment: so it appears Adobe does not send an xml structure as I would expect.  I need name and value... so url post is the best option for me.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I can spot in your question is that you're making use of `XMLReader` here. It's not particularly wrong to use that library - it's intended to parse XML - however the interface it offers for parsing stands in your way.

For example the following line of code does not work with `XMLReader $reader` because it is not offering a [Traversable](http://php.net/traversable) over name/value pairs:

```
foreach ($reader as $name => $value) {
```

Therefore using it within foreach doesn't help you much to get the job done. What you probably want to use instead is [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement). It's more fitting for XML document traversal as it allows such kind of traversals and more direct access of values. Check the [*basic usage examples*](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic).

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('php://input');
$xml->asXML('php://output'); // review submitted (+ loaded + parsed) XML

foreach ($xml as $name => $value) {
     echo "$name: $value\n";
}
```

See as well:

- [Dealing with XForms](http://php.net/features.xforms)
- [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic)
- [Can PHP handle a PDF form submitted as a complete PDF document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6284640/367456)